# wrong usage of sprintf?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I have simple test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc , char* argv[] )
{
  unsigned int number=2048;

  char* cpOut;
  char cOut[4]; 
  cpOut=(char*)&cOut[0];
  printf("cOut address= %x \n",&cOut[0]);
  printf("cpOut address = %x \n",cpOut);

  sprintf(&cOut[0],"%d \n", number);

  printf("cOut address= %x \n",&cOut[0]);
  printf("cpOut address = %x \n",cpOut);
};
```

Test run on Linux, gcc 4.3.4:

```
user@server /tmp $ ./a.out 
cOut address= f9f41880 
cpOut address = f9f41880 
cOut address= f9f41880 
cpOut address = f9f41880
```

Test run on Solaris 10,Sun C++ 5.10:

```
bash-3.00$ ./a.out
cOut address= 8047488
cpOut address = 8047488
cOut address= 8047488
cpOut address = 8000a20
```

Could anyone please explain me why pointer cpOut is overwritten by calling sprintf function ?

Answer (score 7):

Because the string `"2048 \n"` doesn't fit in `char cOut[4];`, you're creating a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You are writing 7 bytes ("2048 \n" + NUL) into an array of size 4 on the stack. This will overwrite 3 bytes of whatever is below it on the stack, which in this case is `cpOut`. The new value of `cpOut` shows you this: the first byte is unchanged 0x08, then the next 3 are the last three bytes of the string you're writing: 00 (NUL), 0a ('\n'), 20 (' ').

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a case of buffer overflow. Try making cOut larger, also replace sprintf with the safer snprintf:

```
sprintf(&cOut[0],"%d \n", number);
```

should be changed to

```
snprintf(cOut,sizeof(cOut),"%d \n", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
sprintf(&cOut[0],"%d \n", number);
```

writes 7 characters : "2048 \n\0", but there is space only for 4 of them. The value 0x8000a20 has contains (in reverse order) : space, new line, and character 0.